# how to assign values to an array in a block with Fabricate gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fabrication-gem

I have the following and the hosts (second to last) line isn't working. Is this possible? How would I assign to it for the save?

```
venues = Venue.all
users = User.all
Fabricate.times(16, :event ) do
  venue { venues.sample }
  created_by { users.sample }
  sales_rep { users.sample }
  casting_rep { users.sample }
  hosts << { users.sample(2) }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless hosts is already an array with default value of `[]` the `<<` won't work.

Better might be...

```
hosts { [users.sample, users.sample] }
```

Comment: went with  ` hosts { users.sample(2) }` to ensure uniqueness